# What command convert mjpeg IP camera streaming to mp4 file with lowest CPU usage?

Tags: ffmpeg, ip-camera

like above question, I want find out what ffmpeg command can help me reduce cpu usage when running 50 IP camera (running same 50 command).

My ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg  -f mjpeg -y -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i 'http://x.x.x.x:8090/test1?.mjpg' -r 3 -reconnect 1 -loglevel 16 -c:v mjpeg -an -qscale 10 -copyts '1.mp4'
```

50 command like that take my computer (4 core) 200% CPU

I want this computer can run for 150 camera, any advise?

=========================================================

using -c:v copy can make it faster but fize size is terrible

I try slow down frame rate by 3 with -r 3 or -framerate 3 to decrease file size but not succesful  (because vcodec copy can't do that).

Have any option to force input frame rate by 3?

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: I try many different encoder and compare thier CPU usage,

 mjpeg encoder is best performance for my scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by setting `-c:v mjpeg` you are decoding and re-encoding the stream. set `-c:v copy` to copy the data without re-encoding it.

Comment: -c:v copy make it do nothing except write data to file. This option create a big file size (1.8GB/hour/camera)

Comment: 150 x 1.8 = 270GB/hour

I think 5-600MB/hour/camera is big enough, 1.8GB is far over my expect

Comment: Video encoding takes cpu. You can't have both low CPU and good compression. You can try using x264 ultrafast preset. or an older codec like mpeg-2.

Comment: I tried both x264 and mpeg-2, they take more CPU usage than mjpeg (mjpeg take 3-5%, x264 ultrafast take 4-5% and mpeg-2 take 4-6% CPU for one camera). When i using mjpeg, file size is 200-250MB/hour. Have any way increase a little file size to decrease CPU usage?

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'rtsp://user:password@10.10.10.30/rtsp_tunnel' -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile baseline -crf 18 -f h264 udp://0.0.0.0:3001
```

Comment: Hello! Editing your answer with a little information explaining what you are doing and why could greatly improve this answer.  Thanks!